# OpenCL, direct access to host memory from GPU kernels

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Is there any way to allocate memory on host, that is accessible directly from GPU, without copying?

Like cudaHostGetDevicePointer in CUDA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use clCreateBuffer with flags containing one of:

- CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR
- CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR

Which does what you want. For more information visit the man page of [clCreateBuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html).

Comment: sorry, i did not clarified properly - have read about thouse options, but CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR can be cached in device memory - it is not allowed for my task.

CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR - "allocate memory from host accessible memory..." - will this memory be accessible from device?

cudaHostGetDevicePointer uses raw DMA via bus, as i know - would like to find something similiar

Comment: There is nothing 100% similar, OpenCL is a lot more generic that CUDA. All CL buffers are accessible from the device side, including the ones allocated using CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR.